# Plugin error "array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer"

Tags: plugins, php, array

Checking the Query Monitor, it's throwing out this error,

> array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

which relates to this function:

```
public function lsx_team_scporder_get_terms_orderby( $orderby, $args ) {
    if ( is_admin() )
        return $orderby;

    $tags = $this->get_lsx_team_scporder_options_tags();

    if ( ! isset( $args['taxonomy'] ) )
        return $orderby;

    $taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];
    if ( is_array( $taxonomy ) && count( $taxonomy ) == 1 )
        $taxonomy = $taxonomy[0];
    if ( ! array_key_exists($taxonomy, $tags ) )
        return $orderby;

    $orderby = 't.lsx_team_term_order';
    return $orderby;
}
```

Why is it throwing out that error?

Comment: I got this error today (2020-03-27) after updating WordPress to 5.3.2 (using theme *"Responsive"*). It happened on submitting updates to an existing blog post. It seems to be theme specific (and updating to the new version of the theme released today did not fix the problem). The workaround is to change to another theme (at least during adding/changing content) - I used the official "Twenty Twenty" theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) the `array_key_exists()` function takes as first argument *"any value possible for an array index."*, again looking up for [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in the docs we can get that *"The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type."*, which also corresponds to the error you see from the Query Monitor.

Meaning that the `$taxonomy` variable that is passing to the `array_key_exists()` is not either a string or integer.

You can debug the `$taxonomy` variable, by making a `var_dump($taxonomy);`.

Hope, that helps.